# Adobe air application (HTML) launch with adminitrator

Tags: air

On Windows, if I install my air application in **C:\** disk, when I run the application, it cannot create the sqlite database with giving **Error #3125**：

```
 SQLError: 'Error #3125: Unable to open the database file.', 
     details:'Connection closed.', operation:'open', detailID:'1001'
```

If I run the application with administrator or install it in **D:\** disk, there's no such error.

So, Is there a way to let the air application run with administrator in any time? And showing UAC dialog-box is OK.

Comment: Probably if you want create sqlite database file in AIR .Create database file in applicationStorageDirectory instead of c:\ or d:\ also don't create applicationDirectory (installed directory because security/permission error will thrown).So that you can avoid all errors.

Comment: @RajaJaganathan. Great! The `applicationStorageDirectory` solved my problem. The error disappeared just now, why not post an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably if you want create sqlite database file in AIR .Create database file in applicationStorageDirectory instead of c:\ or d:\ also don't create applicationDirectory (installed directory because security/permission error will thrown).So that you can avoid all errors.